# how to get text with using substring

Tags: android

I try to get only this part **"9916-4203"** in **"Region Code:9916-4203 "** in android. How can I do this?

I tried below code, I used substring method but it doesn't work:

```
firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(message.substring(11, 19));
```

Comment: You can´t parse a number with a line inside......

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a very complete problem description. Your question will be more readily answered and better received if you say how things aren't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that string contains "Region Code:" couldn't you do a replace?

```
message = message.replace("Region Code:", "");
```

Comment: alternatively you can split your string "Region Code:9916-4203".split()[1]

Answer (score 0):

In Java the `substring()` method works with the first parameter being **inclusive** and the second parameter being **exclusive**. Meaning `"Hello".substring(0, 2);` will result in the string `He`.

In addition to excluding the parsing of something that isn't a number like @Opiatefuchs mentioned, your substring method should instead be `message.substring(12, 21)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that you have only one phone number in your `String`, the following will remove any non-digit characters and parse the resulting number:

```
     public static int getNumber(String num){
     String tmp = "";
     for(int i=0;i<num.length();i++){
        if(Character.isDigit(num.charAt(i)))
        tmp += num.charAt(i);
     }
     return Integer.parseInt(tmp);
    }
```

Output in your case: `99164203`

And as already mentioned, you won't be able to parse any `String` to `Integer` in case there are any non-digit characters

Answer (score 0):

Im going to guess that what you want to extract is the full region code text minus the title. So maybe using regex would be a good simple fit for you?

```
String myString = "Region Code:9916-4203";
String match = "";

String pattern = "\:(.*)";
Pattern regEx = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = regEx.matcher(myString);

// Find instance of pattern matches
Matcher m = regEx.matcher(myString);
if (m.find()) {
    match = m.group(0);
}
```

Variable `match` will contain "9916-4203"
This should work for you.

Java code sourced from http://android-elements.blogspot.in/2011/04/regular-expressions-in-android.html